# Show results from database in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How can I use the content in $displayusercontent which is pulled from the db into the Text field on the jquery.

I've tried this below, but nothing returns, if I echo $displayusercontent on to the page then it works this way.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- my content here-->

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var userContent = <?php echo $displayusercontent; ?>
   </script>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/my/javascript/file/here.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is from my jquery file

```
initIntro: function () {
// display marketing alert only once
if (!$.cookie('intro_show')) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'MyTitle',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: userContent,
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            //image: '../../assets/local/layout/img/avatar.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: true,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: '',
            // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
            class_name: 'my-sticky-class'
        });

        // You can have it return a unique id, this can be used to manually remove it later using
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.gritter.remove(unique_id, {
                fade: true,
                speed: 'slow'
            });
        }, 15000);
    }, 2000);

    $.cookie('intro_show', 1);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQUERY - store php variable and echo it in jquery script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209654/jquery-store-php-variable-and-echo-it-in-jquery-script)

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209654/jquery-store-php-variable-and-echo-it-in-jquery-script/22210380#22210380
Spokey's answer might work, but the "proper" way to do this is explained in the longest answer in the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid. You need to make it a string

```
var userContent = <?php echo json_encode($displayusercontent); ?>;
```

As @dsclementsen pointed out, in this case using *json_encode* is the right option.

Comment: That depends on what the value of `$displayusercontent` is.

Comment: @Quentin True, but from what I see in the commented lines it's a string

Comment: using a plain `echo $somevariable` is a terrible practise that is far to common. `echo json_encode($somevariable)` will put quotes around string variables, escape the variable's content, and handle null values.

Answer (score 1):

After the posts and reading the links attached, this is my code that works.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- my content here-->

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var userContent = <?php echo json_encode($displayusercontent) ?>;
   </script>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/my/javascript/file/here.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks all for the help :-)